# Is it possible to compile a ASP.NET MVC 5 project with a mac

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-code

Hello everyone so first and foremost I am thinking of creating an I-phone app and those could only be created in a mac laptop which runs Xcode. I currently have Visual Studio's in my windows laptop and have a project there (Api that makes database calls to postgres) if I get a mac will this same project compile in Visual Studio Code? https://code.visualstudio.com/ . My project uses Asp.NET MVC 5 which I think is also cross platforms since Asp.NET 5 is. I do not have a mac yet but would like to make an informed decision otherwise I would have to go with Java (I prefer C#) for the api .

Comment: Asp 5 is not the same as mvc 5 :) asp 5 is going to be cross platform, yes. Asp 4 is harder to run cross platforn, which is mvc 5. Asp 5 has mvc 6.

Comment: Wow just learned something new that clears up alot. The MVC 5 templates online look different than mines and now I know i'm running MVC 6. Thanks for the clear up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can with .NET core. This tutorial is a great place to start:

http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet.html

Comment: Thanks for the feedback will start on that